# Linux create and remove file from always-on application

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux

I'm writing in Linux an always on service that opens and writes to file in /tmp, and then should remove file.
I see that space isn't freed from /tmp/ after the process removes the file although the file itself doesn't exist. When I did lsof I see this file is marked as (deleted):
1381    /mnt/unlink     /tmp/mest_elf (deleted)

I read that I for this space to be freed I have to kill my process, but I can't because I need it to run always.

Questions:
1. I'm using posix remove()\unlink() functions. is there any other function that totally removes files?
2. is there a way to remove am lsof file?
3. any other suggestion to me? (remember that I have to write it in c application)

Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is "no". Until your process actually closes the file, it will occupy space. The Linux kernel cannot telepathically determine whether your process will ever use this file again, so as long as it's open the kernel has to assume that the contents of the file must be readily available to your program, if it chooses to `read()` it. If you want to reclaim that disk space, `close()` your file.

Comment: thanks for answer.  but what if I use ofstream? In general I understand that I don't have to close the file explicitly. should I first call close() if I want to delete the file?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. All files that are opened should be closed.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, I had to close the file before call to delete. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In Linux (and other Unix systems) a file exists as long as any process has an open file descriptor referencing the file. You can unlink the file from the filesystem so it's no longer visible, but if there are open handles (file descriptors) to that file then it still sticks around and is a valid file for those processes holding those handles.

This is useful - you don't have the Windows problem of not being able to delete an open file.
But it also means that the storage taken up by the file is not released until all processes having an open handle close that handle.

One easy way to make sure a process has closed all handles is, of course, to terminate the process. But, a process can also just `close()` (or `fclose()` and similar; which ends up as `close`) its open handle to the file and keep running.

Linux/Unix and Windows filesystem semantics are quite different in this area. You should read up on the specific differences.

Comment: ...and don't forget to check returned  error code of `*close()`.